# V93k test method param types missing some acceptable values?

Tags: origen-sdk

When importing test method definitions directly from Verigy I see the following parameter types:

```
[:string, :ContextPins, :int, :double, :PinString, :SpecValue, :SpecVariable, :OptionList, :long, :bool]
```

However, the origen-sdk [docs](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/v93k/#Custom_Test_Methods) show the following types are acceptable:

```
# The type can be :string, :current, :voltage, :time, :frequency, or :integer
```

Some of the Verigy types can easily be converted to `:string (:ContextPins, :PinString, :OptionList, :SpecVariable)` and `:int` can be converted to `:integer`, but the remaining types would require evaluating the intent of the parameter itself (i.e. is this `:double value` a `:frequency` or a `:voltage`?).  Is there a way around this sort of evaluation?  If not, it seems like the following types might be useful:

```
[:float, :bignum, :bool]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, at the point when we are generating the program, the type of a variable doesn't matter much. In most cases, a variable ends up getting represented as a string in the test flow source file:

```
tm_10:
  "arg1" = "0";
  "arg2" = "some_pin";
  "arg3" = "1.523"
```

The test method definition API was originally created to be able to define the built-in AC and DC test method libraries provided by Advantest. Some of the parameters to those methods used units in the test flow file, e.g.

```
  "arg1" = "0A";
  "arg2" = "some_pin";
  "arg3" = "1.523V"
```

So the types like `:voltage` and `:current` were added to support that.
However, I'm not sure if I ever experimented to see if those were really required or not, perhaps they are just thrown away and they are equivalent to Origen's base unit methods: `10.V == 10   # => true`.

I would recommend that for now you just chose the `:string` type for everything and see if it works.
If not, you can add additional types here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/5b89bf287b3d307bd6708c878666f3609a5fd3af/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_method.rb#L5 (it looks like we already have `:double` though it is not mentioned in the docs).
Then you can define how the new type(s) should be formatted in the testflow file here: https://github.com/Origen-SDK/origen_testers/blob/5b89bf287b3d307bd6708c878666f3609a5fd3af/lib/origen_testers/smartest_based_tester/base/test_method.rb#L88